# Calculate and compare IRR among products and companies

Tags: finance, credit

I am trying to calculate return on investment for a couple of companies and their respective products.
I have two main products:

- credit card
- installment loan

Owners would like to be able to compare these two companies (products) return on investment.
What I have done so far is to calculate IRR (similar to XIRR formula and requirements in EXCEL).

1) The issue is that I am calculating IRR on revolving product. Consequently, when a customer is good but withdraws more money than returns the IRR is negative.

2) Additionally, I am not sure I am sure how to incorporate costs in the revolving product - I cannot put % of used principal because of the positive and negative cash-flows.

Any ideas how to overcome these issues (especially point 1); maybe use something instead of IRR as a metric?

Comment: Maybe I don;t see it right. As of today a customer owes an amount X, in other words he has to pay X to clear his account. If this payment of X is included in the calculations, along with past payments he has made and past withdrawals (borrowings) then I don't see how the IRR could be negative.

Comment: U r right. The issues is that I would like to see a realized IRR across 1 year period. The product is a credit card and lets say first usage of the card (limit 1000$) is 500$ in month 0. On month 1 the customer have two options - to return the whole amount or a minimal installament. After doing this he/she can withdraw further up till the limit. This continues till month 12 when we can be of the situation that the customer (as up put it ) awes freshly withdrawn 1000$.

Comment: The thing is that we do not know at this point (month 12) how much or even any of this amount (and when) the customer will return. If for the sake of IRR we consider customer returning complete 1000$ along with interest and taxes in month 12 I have the feeling we won't be quite representative (cause in reality he/she might decide to return in bit across additional 6 months). I may as well be missing something in the logic...